# Vespa semantic search with own dataset

Tags: search, bert-language-model, vespa

I am learning the basics of vector search in Vespa and went through https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/blob/master/msmarco-ranking/passage-ranking-README.md .  I studied the four-part blog too.  Now it would be super interesting to replace the sample dataset `colmini-passage-feed-sample.jsonl` with a similar sample dataset of my own.  Do you have a script, or anything more concrete than the blog part 3?

Answer (score 3):

This worked.
`{"put": "id:msmarco:passage::1001", "fields": {"id": 0, "text": "Vespa is great!"}}` 
We don't actually have to calculate the tensors outside of Vespa.

From Jo Kristian:

> If you bring your own text and without embedding or multi/embedding, the sample app produces it during document processing